# gke autopilot cluster creation failure

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, composer

I am trying to create GKE Autopilot cluster and the creation fails. I see just this error.
"All cluster resources were brought up, but: 1 nodes out of 1 are unhealthy".
Not sure if there are other logs that can provide more specific details. I tried creating a standard cluster and it worked. I added the firewall rules for Google Composer set up. The composer set up was failing as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cant_create_cluster_due_to_health_check_failing) on this issue mentioning potential causes and possible solutions.

As per my understanding, and also considering the error message where it's failing after 83%. I suspect possibly automatically created firewall rules for ingress may have been either deleted or modified. If you check out [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#ingress-fws) documentation, understand the purpose as this permits health checks of a NodePort Service or network endpoint group (NEG). Also, reconfigured DNS for *.gcr.io. would also result in the same time of issue. Therefore, I suggest carefully check each and every point.